# How to get a value from a subcribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to know how I can get a value that I have in a subscribe pass it to a variable and be able to manipulate it example

```
getNumber: number;
```

I want in the same .ts to use that variable getNumber

```
       someMethodTwo() {
          this.someMethod().subscribe(data =>
           
    
    Swal.fire({
      position: 'top-end',
      icon: 'success',
      title: 'it's is the variable '+ getNumber ,
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 1500
    })
    
        }
    
       someMethodOne() {
          this.someMethod().subscribe(data =>
           this.getNumber= data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someMethod returns an observable you can use

```
        .pipe(map(value => {
    // manipulate value here and return it
    }
    )).subscribe((value) => {
    this.yourlocalvaribale = value
)
```